# Making data structure for Key value in Java without collection

Tags: java, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I have written a singly sorted linked list for string type.
Let me tell you what I have to do.

There are words to be stored in sorted linkedlist.
Each word has some variations(or meanings FYI) that also need to be stored in singly sorted linked list.

So basically each word in linked list has linked list of variations.

The problem is how to connect them.
I mean when removing the word would also remove their variations too.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

## Update :

Below is sorted LinkedList :

```
public class LinkedList {

private Node start = null;

private class Node{
    private String value = null;
    private Node next = null;
}
public void insert(){
   // This method will loop from head and inserts in ascending order
}
}
// And other methods like delete etc...
```

Below is what I am trying to do :

```
public class Demo {

public class Word {
    private String stringWord;
    private LinkedList variations;
}

private LinkedList Words;
```

**Note : Use of any API or Collection is not allowed**

Comment: Homework problems require you show us your attempts

Comment: The outer list should not be `List<String>`, but a `List<Word>`, where `Word` has two fields, being the words itself (`String`) and the list of variants (`List<String>`).

Comment: @Andreas how can I sort List<Word> by string, by using comparator or comparable. how? And I have to use same linked list to sort the List<Word> as well. where my Linkedlist stores only strings.

Comment: @RobbyGoz You make `Word` implement `Comparable<Word>`. Then sorting `List<Word>` and `List<String>` becomes equally simple, because you're actually sorting `List<? extends Comparable>`.

Comment: @Andreas I have updated the question, please add answer by modifying it as you said. I don't know about <? extends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want a "variations" list associated with each word in the main list, you need the main list to be a list of `Word` objects, not just a list of plain `String` objects.

Assuming you've learned about generics, this means that you need to change your `LinkedList` class to use a "type parameter" instead of hardcoding `String`, such that the `value` can be either a `Word` (for the main list) or a `String` (for the variations list).

Since your list needs to be sorted, you need the type parameter to be `Comparable`, hence your code becomes:

```
public class LinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    private Node start = null;

    private class Node{
        private E value = null;
        private Node next = null;
    }

    public void insert(E newValue){
        // code here, e.g.
        //   node.getValue().compareTo(newValue)
    }
}

public class Word implements Comparable<Word>{
    private String stringWord;
    private LinkedList<String> variations;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Word that){
        return this.stringWord.compareTo(that.stringWord);
    }
}

// main list
LinkedList<Word> words;
```

Comment: and also overridden toString() in Word class that will return stringWord, so when printing LinkedList by value.toString() will print words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java generics for LinkedList as follows

```
public class LinkedList<T> {

    private Node start = null;

    private class Node {
        private T value = null;
        private Node next = null;
    }
}

// for string type
LinkedList<String> variations = new LinkedList<String>();
// for word type
LinkedList<Word> words = new LinkedList<Word>();
```

Comment: Please read my question, Restricted to use any API or Collection.

Comment: then what do u intend to use for sorting the list?

Comment: At the time of insertion, It will loop from head and insert in ascending order. In the LinkedList insert() method.

Comment: The first thing would be making a singly sorted linked list that can store any type like string or objects. But then how to sort object by its field?

Comment: you can use java generics for creating linked list of any type, and if you have your own sort function then while comparing objects, you can use your own compare method.

Comment: I don't know why stackoverflow does not allow multiple answers to be selected. There can be multiple different solutions for same problem. Anyway your answers is right too.